# How to backfill with an Azure DataFactory pipeline then convert it to a running schedule?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a large number of blobs containing log data that needs to be copied into an azure sql table, and more blobs will be arriving on a regular basis. Blobs are named in the format `[ORIGINALTARFILENAME].tar.gz.log`.

How can you use data factory so that it performs the initial backfill without timing out and then convert the same pipeline to run on a regular schedule such that no blob gets processed twice?

Is it essentially:

1. Create one-off process
2. Open process in VS
3. Amend json to include a schedule of some sort
4. Deploy changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how exactly your data is organised. Data Factory works best with datasets that can be easily partitioned into time-based slices. If your `ORIGINALTARFILENAME` contains the date and time the blob was created, you can achieve what you want in a simple way with just a single pipeline.

You can use this example from the official documentation as a starting point: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-blob-connector/

Then just set your activity `startDate` far enough in the past to pick up all of the blobs that are already there. The backfill will run in parallel with new slices coming in (increasing the activity `concurrency` will make sure nothing gets starved) and you won't have to treat it in any special way, since each blob will correspond to exactly one slice and thus get processed exactly once.